# How to run tasks of a process instance in a single worker

Tags: workflow, zeebe

For simplicity, assume I have a workflow with 2 tasks.

`Task A`: generate files for input.

`Task B`: upload `Task A`'s files to persistence layer.

If I have multiple workers (for scaling) subscribed to both task types, how do I ensure the same worker executes both tasks? Is it possible to tweak queues so that a queue is assigned to a single worker and all tasks from a process instance goes to that queue?